# Converting telephone numbers into "tel:" hyperlinks with regular expression replacement

Tags: php, regex, string

I have the following being extracted from a database:

> Switchboard:265-7404-6,Marketing Hotline: 265-7403, B'ce: 333-6848

I want to convert it to something like this in PHP:

[image: Expected formatting of data]

In the event of extension as: `265-7404-6` it only parses: `265-7404`

```
function printdir()
{
   $mysqli = new mysqli(constant("host"),constant("username"),constant("password"), constant("database"));

   $storedProc = "SELECT * FROM `directory`;";
   $result = $mysqli->query($storedProc);

   if($mysqli->affected_rows>0)
   {
       while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
          echo $row['telephone']; /*Formatting here*/
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the PHP code that you use to extract the information from the database?

Comment: function printdir()
{
$mysqli =  new mysqli(constant("host"),constant("username"),constant("password"), constant("database"));
       $storedProc = "SELECT * FROM `directory`;";
       $result = $mysqli->query($storedProc);
       if($mysqli->affected_rows>0)
       {
       while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
          
           echo $row['telephone']; /*Formatting here*/
 }
 }
}

Comment: Those `constant()` calls are redundant. You could just say `new mysqli(host, username, password, ....)`

Comment: It has to do a find and replace.

Comment: Constants are in a config file:   define("host","localhost");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <?php

function format_number($phone){
    $phone = preg_replace("#[^\d{10}\s]#",'',$phone);
    if(strlen($phone)==7)
        {
         $area = substr($phone,0,3);
    $prefix = substr($phone,3,4);

    $format = $area."-".$prefix;
    $phone = "<a href=\"tel:".$format."\">$format</a>";
    return($phone);
        }
     if(strlen($phone) != 10) return(False);
    $area = substr($phone,0,3);
    $prefix = substr($phone,3,3);
    $number = substr($phone,6,4);
    $format = $area."-".$prefix."-".$number;
    $phone = "<a href=\"tel:".$format."\">$format</a>";
    return($phone);
}

function telephoneText($string)
{
$format_one.= '\d{10}'; //5085551234

$format_two_and_three .= '\d{3}(\.|\-)\d{3}\2\d{4}'; //508.555.1234 or 508-555-1234

$format_four .= '\(\d{3}\)\-\d{3}\-\d{4}'; //(508)-555-1234

$format_five .='\d{3}\-\d{4}'; //(508)555-1234

$format_five_seven .='\d{7}';
$string = preg_replace("~({$format_one}|{$format_two_and_three}|{$format_four}|{$format_five}|{$format_five_seven})~e", 'format_number("$1")', $string);

return $string;
}



?>
```

Thats is the what i was trying to achieve. Thanks guys..

Answer (score 1):

```
$telnumber = explode('-', $row['telephone'], 3));

echo $telnumber[0].'-'.$telnumber[1];
```

The extension and anything after the second value will be in $telnumber[2]

Comment: Sorry, just noticed you tagged it regex, and I ignored that. Still, this should work.

Comment: This will not work. It has to find and replace as the image above. The telephone number has description and text with it. e.g Human resources : 343-3433. I want to enable mobile dialing.